# Getting data based on last date of data existance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view that looks at several tables. Each table contains a daily snapshot of the data ( if something new gets added then everything from before plus anything new gets inserted). In order to get he latest data I built a query like this:

```
Select * from cu.vwmastertable
where processdate = cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate()-1,112) as int)
```

Processdate is the way to tell our daily snapshot. and its in this format: 20210303.

However there are some days where the data fails to get updated. So the query I used returns no data.

I tried using:

```
Select * from cu.vwmastertable
where processdate = ( select max(process) date from cu.vwmastertable)
```

but that this runs for an hour+.

I'm trying to use the

```
cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate()-1,112) as int)
```

if there is data if not get the previous day

```
cast(convert(varchar(8),getdate()-2,112) as int)
```

Any Ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a view, so I would suggest window functions:

```
select *
from (select m.*, dense_rank() over (order by processdate desc) as seqnum
      from cu.vwmastertable m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

You should be able to make this more efficient by only selecting recent dates . . . say the most recent week:

```
select *
from (select m.*, dense_rank() over (order by processdate desc) as seqnum
      from cu.vwmastertable m cross join
           (values (convert(date, dateadd(day, -7, getdate()))) ) v(dte)
      where processdate >= year(v.dte) * 10000 + month(v.dte) * 100 + v.dte
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

You might also be able to add indexes to speed up your version, but without understanding the code that is actually running (i.e. the view definition), it is not possible to make concrete suggestions.

Comment: Thank you, I will try your suggestion :). The view is large and contains over 20 tables. It would take a while to define the underlying tables lol. But i do understand that it would make it easier to give a better answer.

Comment: @WWaldo . . . The advantage of the window function is that only evaluates the view once.  The filtering might greatly reduce the data . . . but perhaps you can just get the processdate from one of the base tables and not fiddle with the view for that.